# How can I sanitise the explode() function to extract only the marker I require?

Tags: php

I have some php code that extracts a web address. The object I have extracted is of the form:

```
WEBSITE?flage=2&fgast=48&frat=1&sort=D&fsrc=2&wid=bf&page=1&id=16123012&source=searchresults
```

Now in PHP I have called this object `$linkHREF`

I want to extract the id element only and put it into an array (I'm bootstrapping this process to get multiple id's)

So the command is:

```
$detailPagePathArray = explode("id=",$linkHREF); #Array
```

Now the problem is the output of this includes what comes after the id tag, so the output looks like:

```
echo $detailPagePathArray[0] = WEBSITE?flage=2&fgast=48&frat=1&sort=D&fsrc=2&w
echo $detailPagePathArray[1] = bf&page=1&
echo $detailPagePathArray[2] = 16123012&source=searchresults
```

Now the problem is obvious, where it'd firstly picking up the `"id"` in the `"wid"` marker and cutting it there, however the secondary problem is it's also picking up all the material after the actual `"id"`. I'm just interested in picking up `"16123012"`.

Can you please explain how I can modify my explode command to point it to the particular marker I'm interested in?

Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you using a built-in function like `parse_str` or `parse_url`?

Comment: Don't use `explode()` to parse a query string. use the purpose built [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str)

Comment: So would it just be:
parse_str($linkHREF,$output);

echo $output['id'];

to get the 'id' ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in functions provided for the purpose.

For example:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.example.com?flage=2&fgast=48&frat=1&sort=D&fsrc=2&wid=bf&page=1&id=16123012&source=searchresults';
$qs = parse_url($url);
parse_str($qs['query'], $vars);
$id = $vars['id'];
echo $id;        // 16123012

?>
```

References:

- [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)
- [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: The problem is I don't have the complete url, as you've defined in the $url object. I modified the code to this, and it doesn't seem to work:

parse_str($linkHREF['query'], $vars);
   $id = $vars['id'];
echo $id;

Comment: I interpreted `WEBSITE` as a placeholder for a real one. If you have something other than a URL post exactly what you do have.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that you are getting &id=123456 only once in your object, then below

```
$linkHREF = "WEBSITE?flage=2&fgast=48&frat=1&sort=D&fsrc=2&wid=bf&page=1&id=16123012&source=searchresults";
$str =  current(explode('&',end(explode('&id', $linkHREF,2))));

echo "id" .$str; //output id = 16123012
```